# How to fix css height of dynamic body and dynamic footer

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Simply put I have 3 elements,

```html
    <div>
        <Header/>
    </div>  
    <div>
        <Body/>
    </div>   
    <div>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
```

The header is a static but undefined height.
The body is an accordion that when expanded should overflow into a scroll bar
The footer is also an accordion that should always be showing but can minimize to only show its header rather than header + content.

What I need to have happen is to have the header always displayed in full, have the accordionFooter always display as much as it wants (whether header + content, or just header), and finally let the bodyAccordion display as much as it can and then overflow into a scroll bar.

Here's what I have so far.

```
    Container: {
        height: '100%',
        minHeight: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    SectionContainer: {
        flex: '1',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        position: 'relative'
    },
    bodyAccordion: {
        overflowY: 'auto'
    },
    footerAccordion: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '0px',
        right: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    }
```

The html is considerably more complex so here is a simplified version

```html
    <div className={Container}>
      <MyHeader/>
      <div className={SectionContainer}>
        <div className={bodyAccordion}>
          <MyAccordion/>
        </div>
        <div className={footerAccordion}>
          <MyFooterAccordion/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When the above code runs the bodyAccordion will overflow into the footeraccordion rather than increasing the size of the scrollable wheel.

Here's a jsFiddle that shows the issue
https://jsfiddle.net/jackyFrosty/mwz62bh9/2/

Comment: Can you add your minimal code to fiddle and provide the link?

Comment: a flex approach (w)could be https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoWrQW there's many duplicate. the unknown in your question is about the min-height of your footer here ..

Comment: @AdityaSrivast Added JsFiddle to the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to to asign in your container class `min-height:100vh`. It happens because your `100%` is equal to your child's labels

Answer (score 0):

```js
var headerheight= document.querySelector("header").offsetHeight;
var footerheight= document.querySelector("footer").offsetHeight;
var contentheight = window.innerHeight -(footerheight+headerheight);
document.querySelector(".content").style.height= `${contentheight}px`;
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
header{
height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
footer{
height:50px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.content{
  background-color:skyblue;
  width:100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.inner{
height:500px;
width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">body</div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

i used javascript to get header and footer height so u can calculate  the body height for remaining screen height !

Answer (score 0):

> When the above code runs the bodyAccordion will overflow into the footeraccordion rather than increasing the size of the scrollable wheel.

This is happening because you have given `position: absolute` to your footer. Get rid of it and the bodyAccordion will stack over your footer. 
If you want the scroll to work, you should restrict the height of your bodyAccordition. Currently there's no restriction on it. 
As Sergio has explained in his answer, it will be better if you go with `100vh` instead of `100%`

> let the bodyAccordion display as much as it can and then overflow into a scroll bar

Finally for it, get rid of `flex:1`. This will make your `bodyAccordition` to take up maximum space above footer.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers everyone,
I was able to figure this out by using the following

```html
    <div className='header'>
      <MyHeader/>
    </div>
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='content'>
        <MyContent/>
      </div>
      <footer className='footer'>
        <MyFooter/>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

```css
    container: {
        position: 'relative',
        height: 'calc(100vh - 95px)',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    header: {
        height: '35px',
        width: '100%'
    },
    content: {
        overflowY: 'auto',
        flex: '1'
    },
    footer: {
        marginBottom: '0px',
        textAlign: 'left'
    }
```